# animation to UIImageView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiimage

I create a view controller and i put a UIImageView in it, I made an `NSArray` that contains the images and I passed in the `UIImageView`, and I added a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` for left an right swiping.

This code works but the images come when swiping like boom without effects or transition, is there a way to add a simple transition between them?

Here is the code:

```
NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                 @"1-r.png",
                 @"2-r.png",
                 @"3-r.png",
                 @"4-r.png",
                 @"5-r.png",
                 nil];

UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender direction];

switch (direction) {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
        imageIndex++;
        break;
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
        imageIndex--;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

imageIndex = (imageIndex < 0) ? ([images count] - 1) : imageIndex % [images count];
_imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];
```

Comment: This is Cocoa Touch, not Cocoa (that would be an OS X question then). Consider formatting your code properly. Adding whitespace when necessary makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

add a UIImgaView to your viewcontroller and create an IBOutled imgView. add the following code to your viewcontroller's .m file.

```
- (UIImage *) prev {
    NSInteger index = [self.imgView.animationImages indexOfObject: self.imgView.image];
    if (index > 0) {
        return [self.imgView.animationImages objectAtIndex: index - 1];
    }
    return self.imgView.animationImages.lastObject;
}

- (UIImage *) next {
    NSInteger index = [self.imgView.animationImages indexOfObject: self.imgView.image];
    if (index < self.imgView.animationImages.count - 1) {
        return [self.imgView.animationImages objectAtIndex: index + 1];
    }
    return [self.imgView.animationImages objectAtIndex: 0];
}

- (void) swipeRight {
    UIImageView *topView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: self.imgView.frame];
    topView.image = [self prev];
    topView.alpha = 0.0;
    [self.view addSubview: topView];
    [self animateImages];
}

- (void) swipeLeft {
    UIImageView *topView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: self.imgView.frame];
    topView.image = [self next];
    topView.alpha = 0.0;
    [self.view addSubview: topView];
    [self animateImages];
}

- (void) animateImages {
    UIImageView *topView = self.view.subviews.lastObject;
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 delay: 0.0f options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:
     ^(void) {
         topView.alpha = 1.0;
     } completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
         self.imgView.image = topView.image;
         [topView removeFromSuperview];
     }];
}

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    NSArray *imageNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
             @"1-r.png",
             @"2-r.png",
             @"3-r.png",
             @"4-r.png",
             @"5-r.png",
             nil];
    NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *filename in imageNames) {
        [images addObject: [UIImage imageNamed: filename]];
    }
    self.imgView.animationImages = images;
    self.imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.imgView.image = [images objectAtIndex: 0];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(swipeRight)];
    rightSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(swipeLeft)];
    leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.imgView addGestureRecognizer: leftSwipe];
    [self.imgView addGestureRecognizer: rightSwipe];
}
```

Comment: dude, this code does not work it gave me this :"implicit conversion from enumeratoin type 'enum uiviewanimation"

Comment: man, the warning that we're talking about before is gone but the photos in NSArray still appear with no transition plzz help.

Comment: And plzz if , can you make for me a sample that contain a uiimage,that contains images and when swiping left or right the other image in the array appear with transition. there's my mail if you want to help me out of this : alaahershy@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks for your help but forget about it it crash my app, plzz if you want send me this sample to my mail to understand what's happening Huge Thanks In Advance